# Does query execution time differs based on different query param value with huge table?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-batch, query-optimization, mssql-jdbc

We are using spring boot, SQL server and Azure cloud.

The goal is to update the 2000 records batch by batch in a table which has 52 
million rows without using a native query.

The table has one foreign key which has a significant amount of rows for each and it is partitioned by foreign key value.

Sample table,

```
seq |  id | value
-------------------
1   | A1  | v1  
2   | A1  | v2  
3   | B1  | v3
4   | B1  | v4
```

...
The actual query is,

```
select * from sample where id=? and value in (?) 
2 parameter will have 2000 strings.

using Spring data JPA repository methods.
```

A1 has 100K records.
B1 has 400K records.

when I execute the query with A1 and 2000 values.it took 17 seconds to fetch.
with B1 and another 2000 values (which A1 don't have) took 70 seconds to fetch from the application.

But when I execute the same query in SSM it just takes 3 seconds.

Is it because of B1 filtering from 400K/52M and A1 from 100K/52M?

connection string has,`sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;` and both column has index also.

Tried CriteriaUpdate for each row, but same results - 35s for 2K/100K/52M and 2 minutes for 2K/400K/52M. so dropped it and now trying this, fetch all at once and update all at once.anyways update is happing faster, Only fetching takes time.

Note:
We didn't use spring batch for this particular process because of the records will be read from Flatfile and each row in the file have to be updated in that table. so there's a reader to read row from file, processor massage the DTO and in writer trying to do this update.chunk size 2000.

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I have gone through that article. in my case timing differs based on different query param value which has big volume. time getting incremented based on volume it filtering from.i'm trying to fix this using that article too. but mean need help anyways.

Comment: `select * from sample where id=? and value in (?)  OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It is working and faster than ever.Now fetch took milli seconds.

My JDBC connection string in property file have `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;`.

But it is actually being picked from the deployment.yaml file which doesn't have it.

**`sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;`**

doc,

> If the sendStringParametersAsUnicode property is set to "true", String parameters are sent to the server in Unicode format.
>
> If the sendStringParametersAsUnicode property is set to “false", String parameters are sent to the server in non-Unicode format such as ASCII/MBCS instead of Unicode.
>
> The default value for the sendStringParametersAsUnicode property is "true".
>
> Note: The sendStringParametersAsUnicode property is only checked when sending a parameter value with CHAR, VARCHAR, or LONGVARCHAR JDBC types. The new JDBC 4.0 national character methods, such as the setNString, setNCharacterStream, and setNClob methods of SQLServerPreparedStatement and SQLServerCallableStatement classes, always send their parameter values to the server in Unicode regardless of the setting of this property.

Thank you.